# Permission error when pushing file to Google Container

Tags: docker, sdk, cloud, google-container-registry

I am working my way through the quickstart to create a container in Google cloud.

I get an authorization error when I try to push a file to a container.  I have worked through every previous step without an error but then I get a message saying I am not authorized

I have tried using the recommended authorization methods:
gcloud auth configure-docker and I did not get an error.

I successfully tagged the file:
docker tag quickstart-image gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/quickstart-image:tag1

I went to the next step:

docker push gcr.io/ali-dev-1/quickstart-image:tag1

Here is what I get

unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication